# MemoryError python 3

Tags: python, postgresql, out-of-memory

I created a python script with a date argument which allows to extract data from a file (4.2 MB) to feed a table; when executing it shows me this error :

```
  File "./insert_pru_data.py", line 136, in <module>
    importYear(year)
  File "./insert_pru_data.py", line 124, in importYear
    SQLrequest += "(" + ", ".join(data_to_insert[i]) + "),\n"
MemoryError
```

My Code:

```
def importYear(year):
  go = True
  if isAlreadyInserted(year):
    if replace == False:
      print("donnees pour annee " + year + " deja inserees, action annulee")
      go = False
    else:
      print("donnees pour annee " + year + " deja inserees, les donnees seront remplacees")
      deleteData(year)

  if go:
    data_to_insert = getDataToInsert(data)
    SQLrequest = "INSERT INTO my_table (date_h, day, area, h_type, act, dir, ach) VALUES\n"
    i = 0
    print(data_to_insert)
    while i < len(data_to_insert) - 1:
        data_to_insert[i] = ["None" if element == None else element for element in data_to_insert[i]]
        SQLrequest += "(" + ", ".join(data_to_insert[i]) + "),\n"
    SQLrequest += "(" + ", ".join(data_to_insert[len(data_to_insert) - 1]) + ");"

    with psycopg2.connect(connString) as conn:    # Ouverture connexion a la base
      with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(SQLrequest)
        cur.execute("COMMIT")
        cur.close()

importYear(year)
```

, someone help me to know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you have a ridiculously huge amount of data in `data_to_insert`, and you're running out of memory (possibly on a 32 bit build of Python where you're limited to ~2 GB of virtual address space no matter how much RAM you have). We have no idea where `data_to_insert` came from, so that's all that can be said.

Comment: ```data_to_insert``` is list came from file csv

Comment: I get data from csv file and with anathor function return ```data_to_insert``` like a list

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly, avoid constructing an SQL query like this; sooner or later, one of the values to be inserted will have something like a quote and then everything will break. It's one of the more common security problems on the internet (SQL injection).

  The `cur.execute()` function can take two arguments - the query (with placeholders) and then the values to be inserted:

  ```
  cur.execute("insert into tbl (a, b) values (%s, %s)", (1, 2))
  ```
- Rather than inserting all the data at once, read them from the file in groups of 100 or 1000 or something; small enough to fit into memory easily, large enough that there aren't too many round-trips.
- There is an [`execute_values()` function](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values) which does exactly what you want; you give it a query and a list of tuples:

  ```
  execute_values(cur, "insert into tbl (a, b) values %s", [(1, 2), (3, 4)])
  ```